# Emacs load file from command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, emacs, text-editors

When I was on Ubuntu, I would open files with Emacs on the command line like this:

```
$ emacs -nw file.txt
```

or

```
$ emacs /etc/sysctl.conf
```

When I use Kali and type the above, no file is opened and I am instead put in the *scratch* buffer.
Then I have to ``C-x C-f file.txt'' to open file.txt

I have read the emacs man file but cannot see any command line argument for opening files.

I am not sure if this is a Kali problem, but mg and other text editors and programs work fine in opening files.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider filing a bug for Emacs: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, if you think the problem is with Emacs and not with your platform. You can also try `emacs --file=FILE`, that is, explicitly use the `--file=` command-line option.

Comment: I tried the ``--file=test.txt'' option but still get taken to \*scratch\*.  Maybe it is a bug with Emacs itself but I think the problem is with Kali since it is giving me trouble in other things as well.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check your `.bashrc` for aliases, and check `which emacs`, both to see if it's loading the binary directly or some other script that then starts emacs.